# Stack too deep problem

Tags: go-ethereum, struct, constructor, stack

I try to add more property to the scenario struct but when I run the compile the same error appear:

```
 struct Scenario {
        uint id;
        address payable author;
        address editor;
        string title;
        string objective;
        uint256 price;
        string copyrigthDate;
        string patientCase;
        string EnvironmentFidality;
        string MedicalDevices;
        string briefingDescription;
        string EventFlow;
        string debriefingDescription;

    }
```

The error message:

```
PS C:\Users\user\desktop\chainlist-truffle5> truffle compile

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\ChainList.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Ownable.sol

Error: CompileError: InternalCompilerError: Stack too deep, try using fewer variables.

Compilation failed. See above.
    at Object.compile (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\workflow-compile\legacy\index.js:72:1)
Truffle v5.0.40 (core: 5.0.40)
Node v10.16.0
```

So, what the best solution in this case? should I create nested structures??

Comment: How are you using it?

Comment: The best solution (which is also the only solution) is what the error message tells you to do: `try using fewer variables`.

Answer (score 3):

The number of variables you are allowed to use is limited.

I encountered this error a lot of times in the past. It is very frustrating.

However, there is no good solution to this problem.

You have to obey to what the error log tells you: `Use fewer variables`.

This is very unfortunate. But your best chance might be creating a second `struct` which stores the other variables you may need. (e.g. splitting the amount of variables evenly on two `structs`)